# Rewrite get parameter with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get, url-rewriting

i want a htaccess url like

```
mysite.com/category/1
```

for

```
mysite.com/category.php?cat=1
```

**my htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Have an simple idea ?
Thank you :-)

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not capturing the right information (you should split the name from the number) and you are not adding the query variable:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

should be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?cat=$2 [NC,L]
                   ^^^^^ capture the number
             ^^^^^ capture the name
```